# How To Read Json File in GWT?

Tags: java, json, gwt

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":     "sachin",   
        "salary":      56000,     
    }       
}
```

This is my `json` file.
now i want to only read it.

When i write last line,it gives me `NullPointerException`.

```
JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseLenient(json);
JSONObject employeeObject = value.isObject();
System.out.println(employeeObject.get("name").isString().stringValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseStrict(json);
JSONObject employeeObject = (JSONObject) value.isObject().get("employee");
```

Currently you are not evaluating an object "employee" - you are evaluating a json object which has an "employee" object as its only child.

Comment: But when i write this.it gives me error com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONException: Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }. on JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseStrict(json);

Comment: ok..I have done with it.But can you tell me the difference between parseStrict And parseLenient method.

Comment: This is from the documentation for parseLenient: `Evaluates a trusted JSON string and returns its JSONValue representation. CAUTION! This method calls the JavaScript eval() function, which can execute arbitrary script. DO NOT pass an untrusted string into this method.`

Comment: In your case, it's the dangling comma after `56000`. It's valid in a JavaScript object literal, but not in JSON.